# What does this error in calling a method mean?

Tags: vala

I have just started out in Vala, and I tried to make a simple program that asks two inputs:

1. An int that specifies a cycle degree; and
2. A char that contains I / R for either an iterative or recursive process.

Just before compiling, I got this error:

```
test0.vala:8.5-8.16: error: Access to instance member `test0.test_exec' denied
        test_exec(q);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^ //the entire statement
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

The pastebin for the very simple program is located [here](http://pastebin.com/wz3VGBY9).

Here's a snippet:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    stdout.printf("Greetings! How many cycles would you like? INPUT: ");
    int q=0;
    stdin.scanf("%d", out q);
    test_exec(q);
}

public void test_exec(int q)
{
    //method code here
}
```

Can you please enlighten me about what to do, and some tips? Thanks.

Comment: @Rek: Welcome to code review.  This site is for reviewing working code, not for fixing broken code.  Please refer to the FAQ: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `test_exec` as an instance (non-static) method. Unlike a static method, an instance method needs to be called on an instance of the given class. However you're trying to call it without such an instance and thus get an error.

So you either need to create an instance of the `test0` class and call `test_exec` on that (though that would make little sense since `test_exec` does not depend on or change any state of the object - as a matter of fact the `test0` class  does not have any state) or make `test_exec` as well as the other methods called by `test_exec` static.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me! It worked, but now I have a logical error with my error trapping in the   test_exec  method  :P

Comment: @Lyon: You should probably create a new question for that including all the code and a description of what you want it to do and how that differs from what it actually does.